# How do I dump a table using name with chinese character?

Tags: mysql, character, collation, cjk

I have a table named "测试", when I dump it with mysqldump, it's get:[image]

then, I tried using show tables like '测试' myself, the result have some question mark by the side of "Tables_in_test_sy":
[image]

I know it will work if I change the table name by using English characters, but if I insist using Chinese characters, How can I fix this?

Comment: Use backticks for to quote tablename with national symbols. Use doublequotes for to quote path in the filesystem.

Comment: Try tacking on `--default-character-set=gbk` on `mysqldump`.